# How to deserialise .NET JsonResult DateTime format with Gson in Android?

Tags: android, json, gson

I have a JSON returned from server in this format:

```
{
    "StartDate": "/Date(1451593800000)/",
    "EndDate": "/Date(1483216200000)/"
}
```

And in my POJO:

```
public class Data {
    java.util.Date startDate;
    java.util.Date endDate;
}
```

And my Gson object:

```
private final Gson gson =  new GsonBuilder()
    .serializeNulls()
    .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE)
    .create();
```

When I wanted to parse this JSON I get this error:

```
Unparseable date: "/Date(1483216200000)/" (at offset 0)
```

What is the right way to parse such JSON in Android with Gson?

Comment: If you can, then I would fix the .NET dates since those are strings when they could be longs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done some thing like this, Create a Date Serializer and register it to the GsonBuilder.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Date;

import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;

public class DateDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Date> {

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonElement element, Type arg1,
            JsonDeserializationContext arg2) throws JsonParseException {
        String data = element.getAsString();
        data = data.replace("/Date(", "");
        data = data.replace(")/", "");
        try {
            return new Date(Long.parseLong(data));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to parse Date due to:");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Registering with Gson Builder

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls()
            .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE)
            .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateDeserializer()).create();
```

Comment: Also Use SerializedName annotation for fields .

Comment: it seems that there is no better way :(