# Converting date object from json to android java

Tags: java, android, mysql, json

Am having this kind of json,it has `news_date` object in this weird format

```
"news_date":"\/Date(1452412800000)\/"
```

below is my full json

```
[{"ID":1,"title":"Add News RSS and WordPress feeds into the ultimate Android News app","details":"If you ve ever wanted to create a specialized News app that takes WordPress feeds News feeds and ","photo_name":"hhh.jpg","news_date":"\/Date(1451721600000)\/","category":"News"},{"ID":2,"title":"Groupon","details":"Groupon is one of the best and most popular coupon apps available on Android","photo_name":"kkk.jpg","news_date":"\/Date(1452412800000)\/","category":"News"},{"ID":3,"title":"Kodi","details":"If you ve ever wanted to create a specialized News app that takes WordPress feeds News feeds and ","photo_name":"lll.jpg","news_date":"\/Date(1452672000000)\/","category":"News"},{"ID":48,"title":"Add News RSS and WordPress feeds into the ultimate Android News app","details":"If you ve ever wanted to create a specialized News app that takes WordPress feeds News feeds and ","photo_name":"nnn.jpg","news_date":"\/Date(1483430400000)\/","category":"News"},{"ID":49,"title":"Groupon","details":"Groupon is one of the best and most popular coupon apps available on Android","photo_name":"pp.jpg","news_date":"\/Date(1491721200000)\/","category":"News"},{"ID":50,"title":"Add News RSS and WordPress feeds into the ultimate Android News app","details":"If you ve ever wanted to create a specialized News app that takes WordPress feeds News feeds and ","photo_name":"sss.jpg","news_date":"\/Date(1484121600000)\/","category":"News"},{"ID":51,"title":"Groupon","details":"Groupon is one of the best and most popular coupon apps available on Android","photo_name":"vvv.jpg","news_date":"\/Date(1491721200000)\/","category":"News"}]
```

am able to retrieve all other `json objects` except `news_date` because in my `Mysql table` it's **data Type** is `date` that's why it's behaving like that, how can i retrieve that `object` in `date format`.

**below is my model class**

```
package model;

/**
 * Created by Admin on 1/28/2017.
 */

public class NewsObject {
    private String title;
    private String details;
    private String photo_name;
    private String news_date;


    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(String details) {
        this.details = details;
    }

    public String getPhoto_name() {
        return photo_name;
    }

    public void setPhoto_name(String photo_name) {
        this.photo_name = photo_name;
    }

    public String getNews_date() {
        return news_date;
    }

    public void setNews_date(String news_date) {
        this.news_date = news_date;
    }
}
```

Comment: change response of date and then use simpledateformat to format or parse date

Comment: @AnandSavjani,plz show me how to , am a beginner suppose ma having a String   `String d = sr.getNews_Date();` how can i change that String Name with SimpleDateFomat

Comment: replace `Date(1452412800000)` to `1452412800000` from backend side

Comment: refer this to convert millisecond to time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17624335/converting-milliseconds-to-minutes-and-seconds

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36902369/how-to-deserialise-net-jsonresult-datetime-format-with-gson-in-android/36903948#36903948

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date you are receiving is in Date(Millis). If you have control over it to be changed from where you are receiving then recommended way would be to send it in the ISO format which is 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS+hh:ss'. If you cannot change it then you will need to parse it out like this.

```
 long millis = Long.valueOf(news_date.substring(news_date.indexOf("("), news_date.indexOf(")")));
```

you can then use millis to initialise a date object

```
 Date date=new Date(millis);
```

and then use `SimpleDateFormat` to format the Date and save it.

Comment: plz show me how to attach date to simple date format

Comment: you can refer here http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/simpledateformat.html

Comment: The troublesome `Date` class is now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Comment: Thanks so much,this it has worked